# AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler interfere with external program (world of tanks)

Tags: c#, windows

By adding a focus changed event handler to windows in my program using:

```
Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(myHandler)
```

an external program is unable to run properly. When my program is running and is listening for events, the launcher of world of tanks is unable to start the world of tanks game client. This is problematic as my program is supposed to run 24/7 on multiple computers, and when I know it interfers with one program, it is likely that it can interfer with others.

The code of interest:

```
public static void SetWindowFocusChangeSubscriber()
{
    AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler focusHandler = new AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChange);
    Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(focusHandler);
}
private static void OnFocusChange(object src, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    return;
}
```

So does anyone know why this is? And how to fix it? Do I need to avoid using the Automation library?

Edit: Oh and btw, my program is in no way affiliated with world of tanks, or wants to interact with it. It just wants to detect when the active window changes.

Comment: Multiplayer games are heavily invested in preventing users from cheating.  Anything that *looks* like a program that automates UI, and could thus be used to cheat, is on top of the list.  Contact the game vendor for support.

Comment: Nice input, I didnt think about that.